# cocoa OSX: file path from fileSystemFileNumber (programmatically)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I have an `NSUInteger fileSystemFileNumber`, is there a way to fetch the file's path / NSURL object / the file itself?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I am asking from a programmatic way to solve this, and not via command line. The question is also tagged under "objective-c", "nsurl", "nsfilemanager", etc. Please remove the duplicate tag!

Comment: The duplicate is also using code but there is no coding solution available.  The other tags are meaningless and the duplicate status can only be revoked by a moderator, so you'll have to flag your question for attention from them.